# Is there a (not so) generalized version of Hilbert's Theorem 90?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, galois-cohomology

I'm sorry if my following question doesn't make any sense.

We know that if $L/k$ is a finite Galois extension then $H^{1}(\mathrm{Gal}(L/k),L^{*})=0$ (Hilbert's theorem 90). However I would like to know if there is some generalized version involving some field extension $M/L$ such that $H^{1}(\mathrm{Gal}(L/k),M^{*})=0$? Here note that $L$ and $M$ are not the same as in the usual version $H^{1}(\mathrm{Gal}(L/k),L^{*})$=0. Also I'm assuming that $M$ is already a $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$-module.

(Edit: If $M/k$ is a Galois extension and $\sigma\in{\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)}$, then choose an automorphism $\tilde{\sigma}:M\rightarrow{M}$ extending $\sigma$ and define $\sigma\cdot{m}:=\tilde{\sigma}(m)$ for all $m\in{M}$. This could give $M$ a structure of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$-module but I'm not sure!)

The motivation of this question is a proof regarding divisors on a smooth curve that I'm trying to understand. In that proof the author says that he will use a generalized version of Hilbert's theorem 90 but he doesn't say what version is. The context is a smooth curve $C/k$ with a generic point $\xi$, a finite Galois extension $L/k$ and a 1-cocycle $f:\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)\rightarrow{L(\xi)^{*}}$ and then the author says "by a generalization of Hilbert's theorem 90 this 1-cocycle is a 1-coboundary", so I'm assuming that the version is something like $H^{1}(\mathrm{Gal}(L/k),L(\xi)^{*})=0$ (whereas the usual version only implies $H^{1}(\mathrm{Gal}(L/k),L^{*})=0$).

Could anyone tell me what this generalization could be? I know that there is a generalization involving étale cohomology but I don't think it should be that complicated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're using $\xi$ for both the generic point and the cocycle.

Comment: sorry, I've fixed it

Comment: With your notations, in the tower of extensions M/L/k , the very existence of H^1(L/k, M*) (not to say anything of its nullity) requires an action of Gal(L/k) on M*. You assume that such an action is already given on M, but what is it ? Surely, in the case of M = L(generic point), it is not arbitrary.

Comment: In the proof the action is given as follows: if $\sigma\in{\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)}$ then we consider the automorphism $\tilde{\sigma}$ extending $\sigma$ which satisfies $\tilde{\sigma}(\xi)=\xi$, so if we take $f\in{L(\xi)}$ then $\sigma$ acts on $f$ by means of $\tilde{\sigma}$, i.e. $\sigma\cdot{f}:=f^{\tilde{\sigma}}$ which means that $\tilde{\sigma}$ is acting on the coefficients of $f$.

Comment: I assume that the action of $\sigma\in{\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)}$ on $M$ is similar. We assume that $M/k$ is a Galois extension, so we take $\tilde{\sigma}:M\rightarrow{M}$ which extends $\sigma$ and define $\sigma\cdot{m}:=\tilde{\sigma}(m)$ for all $m\in{M}$. However I'm not sure about this, that's why I was wondering if there is some "generalized" version of Hilbert 90 implying my situation (although I'm starting to believe that it's a consequence of the usual Hilbert 90 together with some exact sequence involving $H^{1}(\mathrm{Gal}(L/k),L^{*})$...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we have $L/k$ a finite Galois extension, and $M=L(\xi)$, with $\xi$ algebraic over $L$. You define the action of $G=Gal(L/k)$ over $M^{*}$

$G\times M^{*}$ $\rightarrow$ $M^{*}$

$(\sigma,x)\rightarrow \tilde \sigma(x)$,

where $\tilde\sigma:M\rightarrow\bar M$ is the unique extension of $\sigma$ to $M$ such that $\tilde\sigma(\xi)=\xi$. It follows that, since $M=L(\xi)$, then $\tilde\sigma\in Aut(M/k)$, and that, by Artin's Lemma,since G is finite, and so $\tilde G$={$\tilde\sigma|\sigma\in G$} is finite,and since clearly $\tilde G$<$Aut(M/k)$, and Fix($\tilde G$)=k($\xi$), then M/k($\xi$) is a finite and Galois extension, and Gal($M/k(\xi)$)=$\tilde G$.
So, what you are really concerned with is $H^{1}(\tilde G, M^{*})$ with the standard action of $\tilde G$ over $M^{*}$ (that is, there is a commuting diagram involving this $\tilde G$-module and the G-module $H^{1}(G, M^{*})$, involving the injective group homomorphism $G\rightarrow \tilde G$,$\sigma\rightarrow\tilde\sigma$) , which is, by Hilbert theorem 90, null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the last part of your answer, do you mean that $H^{1}(G,M^{*})\rightarrow{H^{1}(\tilde{G},M^{*})}$ is injective because $G\rightarrow{\tilde{G}}$ is injective?

Comment: Yes: $H^{1}(\tilde G,M^{*})=1$, and so $H^{1}(G,M)=1$ ,too.

Comment: Actually, the homomorphism $\sigma\rightarrow\tilde\sigma$ gives you a group homomorphism $H^{1}(\tilde G,M^{*})\rightarrow H^{1}(G,M)$, but the former is in truth an isomorphism, so it does not really matter which direction goes the obtained arrow, as it results to be a group isomorphism,too.

Comment: I'm worried by your claimed homomorphim $H^1(\tilde G,M^∗)→H^1(G,M^∗)$. I agree that, by construction $\tilde G≅H:=Gal(L/L∩k(ζ))$, and $H$ may be identified with a subroup of $G$, but that's all. First, there can't be any injection $G→\tilde G$ because $H$ is a priori smaller than $G$. Second, you define an action of $G$ on $M^*$ by "lifting" an element $s$ of $G$ to a "unique" $\tilde s$ of $\tilde G$: this is not possible if $s$ does not fix $L∩k(ζ)$. The point is actually to define an adequate action of $G$ on $M$. Without some extra hypothesis (e.g. about the curve $C/k$), I can't see how.

Comment: @nguyen quang do You're totally right,  I was mistaken. What I wrote two years ago is true only when $L $ and $k (\xi) $ intersect in $k $. In that case there should be no problem.